# Delta Epsilon Continuity proof example

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

Prove, by using the definition of continuity, that

$f(x) = \dfrac{5}{3}$$\sqrt x $ $+$ $3$

is continuous at the point $x=7$.
Definition I have to use is as follows:

> For any $\epsilon$>0, there exists $\delta>0$ such that: whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Do not edit your actual question out from the question just because you've gotten an answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

The thinking that follows applies to the general case where we prove that $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuous everywhere in its domain.

We have $|\frac{5}{3}\sqrt{x} + 3 - \frac{5}{3}\sqrt{7} - 3| = \frac{5}{3}|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{7}| = \frac{5}{3}\frac{|x-7|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{7}}$ for all $x \geq 0$. If in addition we have $|x-7| < 1$, then $6 < x < 8$, so $\sqrt{6} < \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{8}$, and hence $\frac{|x-7|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{7}} < \frac{|x-7|}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{7}}$. Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $\frac{|x-7|}{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{7}} < \varepsilon$ if in addition we have $|x-7| < \varepsilon (\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{7})$. So taking $\delta := \min \{ 1, \varepsilon (\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{7}) \}$ suffices.

Comment: +1 for doing it in "discovery order", and not just presenting the choice of $\delta$ up front.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs, Thanks for appreciating :). I always prefer to do it that way, which is more heuristic.